# Syntax for define a template that takes a template

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates, default-template-argument

I wanted to create a type that holds a generic type type, that, itself, is a template with one argument. So, if my type is called `C`, it could be summarized like `C<T<U>>`.

So, I went for it:

```
#include <vector>

template <template<typename> class T>
class C
{
    // implementation here
};

int main() {
    C<std::vector<int>> myType;
}
```

And I am facing this error:

```
<source>:10:7: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
    C<std::vector<int>> myType;
      ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
```

What is the correct way of force a template to take a type that itself, is a template that expects other template argument?

[Live example.](https://godbolt.org/z/9jrazb7oh)

Comment: What’s the point of constraining it to another template? What’s the goal?

Comment: `std::vector<int>` is not a template, it is a concrete type.  `std::vector` itself is the template.

Comment: Do you want just `typename T`? Or do you only want to accept templates for some reason?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat probably I missused the template word there. I want to have a type, that is able to accept C<T<U>>, being always T a type that must be specified in terms of U.

Comment: 1. Do you want to reject `C<U>`? 2. Given `C<T<U>>`, do you want to know `U`?

Comment: You can declare a template `C` accepting any type, and then define only a partial specialization `C<T<U>>` (leaving the other cases undefined). I fail to see why this is a good idea, though. What you are actually trying to accomplish here? What's the general picture? Why making `C` accepting all types is not OK?

Comment: Are you saying that you want `C` to only accept a template parameter that is itself an instantiated template?  You may need to [edit] this question to clarify what youare trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Do you only want to accept container types?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat probably I am following a convoluted way, but there's some CRTP code behind the scenes, so I wanted to constraint the template. 1.) Yes 2.) Sure, it will be present in a using declaration later

Comment: Can you explain more about how you use CRTP?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat better if you read by yourself https://github.com/Pyzyryab/Zero/tree/physics-library/zero/ifc/physics/quantities On the dimensions module is the initial try to be able to set up derived magnitudes, and one approach I am trying is based on CRTP (origin isn't up to date to my last local changes), but i am pretty sure that you will be able to figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specialize the class for the case you need and let it undefined otherwise

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename  T>
class C;

template <template<typename> typename TT, typename U>
class C<TT<U>>
{
    // implementation here
};

int main() {
    C<std::vector<int>> myType;
    // C<int> myTypeWrong; // compile error
}
```

---

The above does not work before C++17 because `std::vector` has a default for its second template type parameter,

```cpp
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

and before C++17 the part `= std::allocator<T>` is ignored, as far as matching the `std::vector` template template argument with the `TT` template template parameter above, so `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>` never successfully match `C<TT<U>>`. (Same thing holds for `template<typename, typename = void> struct V {};` as it holds for `std::vector`, clearly.)

This, together with the workaround mentioned in a comment and based on the usage of a variadic template parameter for the template template parameter, is explained in *C++ Templates - The Complete Guide* 2nd edition, §12.3.4, page 197-198.

As pointed out in another comment, Clang hasn't adopted the C++17 change to the mentioned part of the standard.

Comment: Care with standard though (pre C++17), `std::vector` has also `Allocator`...

Comment: Also, Clang15 is reporting this:
`<source>:13:25: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'C<std::vector<int>>'`. GCC12 compiles fine, btw

Comment: @AlexVergara, I think that is related to Jarod42's comment.

Comment: @Enlico flags are in C++20

Comment: @AlexVergara, but GCC is not erroring. So one of the two compilers is correct and the other wrong. If clang is wrong, then the things are possibly related and clang is just giving an outdated diagnostic. Since GCC gives in C++14 basically the same error as clang gives in C++14 and in C++17/20, I think it's most likely that GCC is correct.

Comment: @Enlico yes, totally agree. Your response is mostly that what I was expecting, but without having to justify for what I need that things that I asked for. Which is always nice, when the question is all about C++ syntax.

Comment: @AlexVergara, I don't think the others wanted that you justified anything. It's just that some people (including me, tbh) think that maybe some more information about the use case could unveil that you don't need the thing you asked for.

Comment: Use `template <typename...> typename` to make it work in Clang. Clang is in the wrong, they refused to support your usage by default (`-frelaxed-template-template-args` enables it).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I really appreciate your answer. I am still trying to figure out a lot of things about templates, and I usually tend to stick with Clang for... everything. So, thanks for point this

Comment: @Enlico My doubt is purelly a syntax thing, even I am not sure if I will implement it in the code base. Since the language allows it, is just nice to know about it. That's why I am being grateful to you for just answer